# Adding Elements from a List of Lists to a Set?

Tags: python, list, set

I'm attempting to add elements from a list of lists into a set. For example if I had

```
new_list=[['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green']]
```

How would I receive

```
new_set=(['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green'])
```

I'm trying to do this so I can use intersection to find out what elements appear in 2 sets. I thought this would work...

```
results=set()
results2=set()
for element in new_list:
    results.add(element)

for element in new_list2:
    results2.add(element)
results3=results.intersection(results2)
```

but I keep receiving:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the inner lists to tuples, as sets allow you to store only hashable(immutable) objects:

```
In [72]: new_list=[['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green']]

In [73]: set(tuple(x) for x in new_list)
Out[73]: set([('blue', 'purple'), ('black', 'orange', 'red'), ('green',)])
```

Answer (score 3):

> How would I receive

```
new_set=(['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green'])
```

Well, despite the misleading name, that's not a `set` of anything, that's a `tuple` of `list`s. To convert a `list` of `list`s into a `tuple` of `list`s:

```
new_set = tuple(new_list)
```

---

Maybe you wanted to receive this?

```
new_set=set([['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green']])
```

If so… you can't. A `set` cannot contain unhashable values like `list`s. That's what the `TypeError` is telling you.

If this weren't a problem, all you'd have to do is write:

```
new_set = set(new_list)
```

And anything more complicated you write will have exactly the same problem as just calling `set`, so there's no tricky way around it.

---

Of course you can have a `set` of `tuple`s, since they're hashable. So, maybe you wanted this:

```
new_set=set([('blue','purple'),('black','orange','red'),('green')])
```

That's easy too. Assuming your inner `list`s are guaranteed to contain nothing but strings (or other hashable values), as in your example it's just:

```
new_set = set(map(tuple, new_list))
```

---

Or, if you use a sort-based set class, you don't need hashable values, just fully-ordered values. For example:

```
new_set = sortedset(new_list)
```

Python doesn't come with such a thing in the standard library, but there are some great third-party implementations you can install, like [`blist.sortedset`](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sortedset.html) or [`bintrees.FastRBTree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/).

Of course sorted-set operations aren't quite as fast as hash operations in general, but often they're more than good enough. (For a concrete example, if you have 1 million items in the list, hashing will make each lookup 1 million times faster; sorting will only make it 50,000 times faster.)

---

Basically, any output you can describe or give an example of, we can tell you how to get that, or that it isn't a valid object you can get… but first you have to tell us what you actually want.

---

By the way, if you're wondering why `list`s aren't hashable, it's just because they're mutable. If you're wondering why most mutable types aren't hashable, [the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable) explains that.

Answer (score 1):

Make the element a tuple before adding it to the set:

```
new_list=[['blue','purple'],['black','orange','red'],['green']]
new_list2=[['blue','purple'],['black','green','red'],['orange']]

results=set()
results2=set()
for element in new_list:
    results.add(tuple(element))

for element in new_list2:
    results2.add(tuple(element))

results3=results.intersection(results2)
print results3
```

results in:

```
set([('blue', 'purple')])
```

Set elements have to be hashable.

- for adding lists to a set, instead use tuple
- for adding sets to a set, instead use frozenset